# How to write title with center align and subtext aligned right to end of title row?

Tags: html, css

I want to write a title in a web page. The title comes in two lines, where the second line should end at the same place as the first line regardless if I change the size of the browser. The second line should have a smaller font and be italic.
The first line should be center aligned. Bootstrap useful?

Something like this (without the > signs):

```
> MY FIRST WONDERFUL ROW TITLE
>            - best title ever
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <h1>MY FIRST WONDERFUL ROW TITLE
    <span>- best title ever</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
h1 {
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:flex-end;
}
h1 span {
  font-size:smaller;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Many thanks!